# Use Python/Pandas indexed date as condition in holiday list

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I'm opening a CSV file with two columns and about 10,000 rows.  The first column has a unique date and time stamp (ascending in 30-minute intervals, called 'date_time') and the second column has an integer, 'intnum'.  I use the date_time column as my index and then use conditions to sum only the integers that fall into specific date ranges.  All of the conditions work perfectly, EXCEPT the last condition is based on matching those dates with the USFederalHolidayCalendar.

Here's the rub, the indexed date is more complex (eg. '2015-02-16 12:30:00.00000') than the holiday list date (eg. '2015-02-16', President's Day).  So when I run an 'isin' function against the holiday list, it doesn't find all of the integers associated with the whole day because '2015-02-16 12:30:00.00000' is not equal to '2015-02-16', despite the fact that it is the same day.

Code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar, get_calendar 

newcal = get_calendar('USFederalHolidayCalendar')
holidays = newcal.holidays(start='2010-01-01', end='2016-12-31')

filename = "/Users/Me/Desktop/test.csv"

int_array = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0, parse_dates=['date_time'], index_col='date_time')

intnum_total = int(int_array['intnum'][(int_array.index.month >= 2) & 
   (int_array.index.month <= 3) & (int_array.index.hour >= 12) & 
   (int_array.index.isin(holidays) == TRUE)].sum()

print intnum_total
```

Now, I get no errors, so the syntax and functions work "properly", but I know for a fact the holiday match is not working.

Any thoughts?

Thanks ahead of time - this is my first post, so hopefully the formatting and question is clear.

Comment: well...MLK day is in January...try printing out the holidays: `print(*holidays, sep='\n')`.

Comment: My mistake, President's Day... but you get the point.  Edited.

Comment: was trying to replicate and saw that President's Day was 2/16/2015 and MLK 1/19/2015, but didn't see a holiday on 2/19/2015, which is why I printed the dates to make sure.

Comment: Ugh, corrected again to 2/16/15 (thanks G Brown).  But the point remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some some thoughts...

Say you have a list of holidays for 2016:

```
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-12-31')
print holidays.size
```

Which yields:

```
10
```

So there are 10 holidays in 2016 based on `USFederalHolidayCalendar`.

You also have your `DateTimeIndex`, which, let's say is covering 2015 and 2016:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start='2015-1-1', 
                                     end='2016-12-31', freq='30min'))
print idx.size
```

Which shows:

```
35041
```

Now if I would want to see how many holidays are in my 30 min based `idx` I would take the `date` part of the `DateTimeIndex` and compare it to `date` part of the `holidays`:

```
idx[pd.DatetimeIndex(idx.date).isin(holidays.date)].size
```

Which would give me:

```
480
```

Which is `10 holidays * 24 hours * 2 halfhours in an hour`.
Does that sound correct?

**Note** that when you do `index.isin(other_index)` you get back a `boolean` array which is sufficient for indexing, and you don't need to do an extra comparison `index.isin(other_index) == True`

Comment: the number of intervals that fall into the holiday list were much less relevant than matching the dates - but the `.date` to `.date` comparison did the trick, so thank you!.  Also (and I'm a little embarrassed to admit this), I think I was capitalizing the second "t" in DatetimeIndex and was getting thrown there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just access the date from your timestamp and see if it is in your list of federal holidays?  I don't know why you need your second integer index column; I would think a boolean value should suffice (e.g. fed_holiday).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2016-1-1', end='2016-12-31', freq='30min', name='ts'))

df['fed_holiday'] = [ts.date() in holidays for ts in df.ts]

>>> df.fed_holiday.sum() / (24 * 2.)
10.0
```

Comment: The integer column is the vital information I need, the dates are just the index.  I need to conditionally sum up all the integers based on the various conditions - one of which is the date falling on a holiday.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but it doesn't answer the question.  The integers in the second column are crucial.

Comment: I want to sum up a column of number based on the date column with certain conditions - one of which is that the date is on a holiday.

Comment: They'll vary based on different factors, but they are similar to what was asked in the original question.  For example, month >= 2 & month <= 3, and maybe weekday < 5.

Comment: Wow, yeah, definitely don't let anyone else have a chance at answering it... it's been up for two whole hours.  As a reply, I'm expecting someone to tweak my existing code so that it provides the ability to sum up the integer column based on all of the date_time periods that adhere to the multiple conditions I'm trying to pass - including that it is a holiday.